# Error when deleting JWT token: Code generation from strings disallowed for this context, (Electron Forge and React)

Tags: reactjs, electron-forge

Issue Description:
I am using Electron Forge React to develop my application. I have implemented JWT sessions and defined the allowed routes in my routing.js file. However, when I delete the token from local storage, I encounter the following error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/admin/cotizador 404 (Not Found)
VM2137 renderer_init:2 Unable to load preload script: C:\Users\jagg9\OneDrive\Escritorio\ELECTRONJS\electron-forge-react\projects\abx-pqtr\.webpack\renderer\main_window\preload.js
(anonymous) @ VM2137 renderer_init:2
(anonymous) @ VM2137 renderer_init:2
___electron_webpack_init__ @ VM2137 renderer_init:2
(anonymous) @ VM2137 renderer_init:2
compileForInternalLoader @ VM1986 loaders:334
compileForPublicLoader @ VM1986 loaders:270
loadBuiltinModule @ VM2099 helpers:56
Module._load @ VM2102 loader:941
f._load @ VM2134 asar_bundle:2
executeUserEntryPoint @ VM2133 run_main:81
(anonymous) @ VM2082 run_main_module:23
VM2137 renderer_init:2 EvalError: Code generation from strings disallowed for this context
    at ./src/preload.js (VM2140 C:\Users\jagg9\OneDrive\Escritorio\ELECTRONJS\electron-forge-react\projects\abx-pqtr\.webpack\renderer\main_window\preload.js:117:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (VM2140 C:\Users\jagg9\OneDrive\Escritorio\ELECTRONJS\electron-forge-react\projects\abx-pqtr\.webpack\renderer\main_window\preload.js:152:41)
    at VM2140 C:\Users\jagg9\OneDrive\Escritorio\ELECTRONJS\electron-forge-react\projects\abx-pqtr\.webpack\renderer\main_window\preload.js:220:37
    at Object.<anonymous> (VM2140 C:\Users\jagg9\OneDrive\Escritorio\ELECTRONJS\electron-forge-react\projects\abx-pqtr\.webpack\renderer\main_window\preload.js:222:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (VM2140 C:\Users\jagg9\OneDrive\Escritorio\ELECTRONJS\electron-forge-react\projects\abx-pqtr\.webpack\renderer\main_window\preload.js:224:3)
    at Module._compile (VM2102 loader:1269:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (VM2102 loader:1324:10)
    at Module.load (VM2102 loader:1124:32)
    at Module._load (VM2102 loader:965:12)
    at f._load (VM2134 asar_bundle:2:13330)
```

Although the private routes are properly restricted after deleting the token, the routing does not update, and it still tries to access a route that no longer exists.

I would appreciate any insights or solutions on how to resolve this issue.

Steps to reproduce:

Use Electron Forge React to create an application with JWT-based sessions.
Define routes in the routing.js file similar to the provided code snippet.
Store a JWT token in local storage.
Delete the token from local storage.
Observe the error mentioned above.

Additional information:

Electron Forge React version:
React 18, Router 6
Operating System: Im using windows 11

Expected behavior:
After deleting the JWT token, the application should redirect to the appropriate public route or display an error page. The routing should be updated accordingly.